# First order PDE with Method of Characterization.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the P.D.E.
>   $u_x + u_y = 1$
>   subject to the initial condition $u(x, y) = h(x, y)$ for $(x, y) ∈ Γ$ where $Γ$ is a given smooth curve
>   and $h : Γ → \mathbb{R}$
>   is a given smooth function.
>
> a. Find a smooth initial curve $Γ$ passing through the origin and a smooth function $h : Γ →\mathbb{R}$
>   such that a solution to the problem exists in a neighborhood of every point of $Γ$ except the
>   origin. Verify this non-existence at the origin for your example.
>
> b. Now find an initial curve $Γ$ and function $h : Γ → \mathbb{R}$
>   such that the problem has infinitely
>   many solutions. Describe explicitly this infinite family of solutions.

I know that this is a 1st order PDE so I have to use method of characterization.

So far what I got is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau }=1,\frac{\partial Y}{\partial \tau }=1,\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \tau }=1$ and $X(s,0)=x_0(s),Y(s,0)=y_0(s),Z(s,0)=h(x_0(s),y_0(s))$.

So, $X(s,\tau)=\tau+x_0(s),Y(s,\tau)=\tau+y_0(s),Z(s,\tau)=\tau+h(x_0(s),y_0(s))$

That is what my teacher taught me. I don't know how to proceed now toward part a. I really want to learn what is going on there and how to handle this kind of problems. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but then a doubt popped up in my mind: have you ever seen the characteristic ODE? (I think the answer is 'no', but I want to be sure)

Comment: No. What is that? May be I know it but not by that name.

Comment: Other tiny question: does the term noncharacteristic boundary condition say something to you?

Comment: I have no idea about the things you are mentioning. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think it will be difficult for you to have intuition on "where to look for a curve that solves point a)" without the concept of noncharacteristic boundary condition (or, at least, it would be difficult for me). The first ten pages of [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf) should explain you what's happening and give you intuition on how should a curve satisfying a) look like.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Change coordinates $x=s+t,y=s-t$ to new coordinates $(s,t)$. Then the PDE becomes $u_s=1$.
- Next change variable $u(s,t)=s+v(s,t)$ and $h(s,t)=s+k(s,t)$. Then the PDE becomes $v_s=0$. In other words, solutions $v(s,t)$ can only depend on $t$.
- Exercise (a): Choose $\Gamma$ to be the graph of $s\mapsto \exp(-1/s^2)\sin(1/s)$ and $k(s,t)=s$. [The main idea is that $\Gamma$ then is of class $C^{\infty}$ and intersects the $s$-axis infinitely many times in all neighborhoods of the origin. Hence the $s$-independent $v$-solution is forces to depend on $s$. Not possible.]
- Exercise (b): Choose $\Gamma$ to be the $s$-axis with $k(s,t)=k_0$ a constant. The full solution is $v(t)$ such that $v(0)=k_0$.